# Updating an array in a SQL Table with filtered old vales

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Hi All I want to remove all non US numbers in the data base using an SQL Query but I tried tons of things but really did not worked out. Basically I already tried this query below:

```
UPDATE 
  accounts
SET
  sms = array_remove(sms, SELECT
    FROM unnest(sms) pNumber 
    WHERE pNumber NOT LIKE '1%')
```

But it seems to having an error:

My dream algorithm was:

1. Update account's sms colomn by getting old sms value that does not start with '1'
2. Remove them from the array then update each colomn after.

I am using PostgreSQL BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) from the results of a subquery:

```
update accounts
set sms = array(
    select p_number 
    from unnest(sms) as p_number 
    where p_number not like '1%'
    )
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3de47e888ad403684ea0aa7c118be682)

Comment: Ohhh it worked! After hours stucked in this whole. Did not realized I just need to construct this into an array. So that was what I was missing in my college degree. I don't have enough words to thank persons like you.

Comment: just curious you wrote the queries in small letters. Just Realized it why when I viewed your account. :D

Comment: It actually worked, and I successfully did it with your great help :D

Comment: All the better!